# GAE: Restoring Data to Another App shows blank page

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I discovered today a very useful feature in the Admin section, where I can restore data to another application.  This would be a great way to test live data on staging server.

I read this documentation and followed the steps:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Restoring_Data_to_Another_App

Until this step where I am about to restore the data from Google Cloud Storage, everything looks good.

[image]

But just when I click on restore from backup, I get a blank screen shown:

[image]

Its great that google thought about this, but how do I make it work?

Comment: This usually happens when your are sing in with multiple account at once. Behind the scene the Datastore admin functionality shown on an iframe that will display blank if it requires an account to be chosen. Have you tried this with an incognito window with only one account signed in?